# Property definition has inferred type 'some View', involving the 'some' return type of another declaration

Tags: swiftui

It didn't work when I update to xcode 13 beta 4.

show error:

> Property definition has inferred type 'some View', involving the 'some' return type of another declaration

```swift
struct RatingToStar : View {
    var rating: Int
    let star = Image(systemName: "star").foregroundColor(.yellow)
    let fillStar = Image(systemName: "star.fill").foregroundColor(.yellow)

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if rating >= 1 {fillStar}else{star}
            if rating >= 2 {fillStar}else{star}
            if rating >= 3 {fillStar}else{star}
            if rating >= 4 {fillStar}else{star}
            if rating >= 5 {fillStar}else{star}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In beta 4, return types for view modifiers have been cleaned up and made `some View`. The release notes say so:

> View modifier methods return opaque views (some View) rather than
>   complex generic types. (46140669)

This is what's causing the change in behavior. At this time I cannot give you a full explanation on the error message, as I am not entirely confident about it, but I can give you an easy workaround:

```swift
struct RatingToSta : View {
    var rating: Int

    let star = AnyView(Image(systemName: "star").foregroundColor(.yellow))
    let fillStar = AnyView(Image(systemName: "star.fill").foregroundColor(.yellow))

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if rating >= 1 { fillStar } else{ star }
            if rating >= 2 { fillStar } else{ star }
            if rating >= 3 { fillStar } else{ star }
            if rating >= 4 { fillStar } else{ star }
            if rating >= 5 { fillStar } else{ star }
        }
    }
}
```

If I find out more, I'll make sure to come back and update my answer.

Comment: This solution gets rid of the error message but at the expense of efficiency.  By declaring a View as AnyView (or someView (below)), the compiler can no longer (by definition) determine the type of View being returned (e.g. Text, HStack, etc.).  Resolution of the type of View must now happen at run time.  Only use these solutions as a last resort.

Answer (score 13):

you can also fix it by specifying a type of `some View`

```
let star : some View = Image(systemName: "star").foregroundColor(.yellow)
```

Comment: Here in Oct. 2021: Doing this gets the ridiculous error of "some View" and "some View" not matching in a ternary.