# Problems with the keyword "some" with the Swift Charts framework

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm really new to Swift, and am making a simple app to track pellets eaten by my pet axolotl Miyamoto. I am trying to represent the pellet count visually using the [Swift Charts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts). However, I can't quite figure out how to solve this error that I am getting.

> Property definition has inferred type 'State<Chart>', involving the 'some' return type of another declaration`

I get it whenever the **`ForEach`** loop is present, even though my code is quite simillar to [this example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart#:%7E:text=Controlling,chart). Removing the **`ForEach`** loop lets the code build and the build it works fine. I have done some reading on this and `some` is used when declaring a function, but I have no references to `some` in my **`ForEach`** loop. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57134610), but no answers there seem to be relevant to my problem. I have done a lot of googling about this but there is still no solution that works. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
...

struct PelletArr: Identifiable {
    
    var pelletdata: Array<String>
    
    let id: Int = 987654321 // just put some number here to stop errors
}

......

struct ContentView: View {
    
    ......
    
    @State var charliechart: Chart = Chart {
        var pelletarrarr: Array<PelletArr> = []
        var _ = pelletstor.stor.forEach { item in
            pelletarrarr.append(PelletArr(pelletdata: item))
        }
        ForEach(pelletarrarr, id: \.pelletdata[0]) { pelletd in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", DateString().dateNumber(dateStr: pelletd.pelletdata[0])),
                y: .value("Pellet Count", pelletd.pelletdata.count),
                series: .value("Axolotl", "A")
            )
            .foregroundStyle(.green)
        }
        RuleMark(
            y: .value("Fixed", 10)
        )
    }

    ......

}
```

### NOTES:

- `PelletArr` is a wrapper of the actual array, which is stored in the property `pelletdata`
- `......` indicates code I deemed irrelevent
- The formatting of the data storage is `Array<Array<String>>`, here is a small example:

```
[
["1/1/2003", "", "", "", ""]
     ^        ^   ^   ^   ^
  the date    these are all
 (Australia   blank strings,
   format)     1 equals 1 
                 pellet
]
```

- The data is parsed from strings, which is stored in the Swift 'defaults'.

Comment: State shouldn’t be a computed property with body code inside.

Comment: Don't use `@State var charliechart...` for this, see: [creating charts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/creating-a-chart-using-swift-charts)
 
 You could try using `@ViewBuilder func charliechart() -> some View { Chart { .... } }`
 with no procedural code inside, put those outside of the view body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are very new to SwiftUI,
try this example code using a simple `Chart{...}` call inside the view body.
The data is represented as an array of `struct Pellet`, that you load
when the View appears.

Read more about how to make charts here:  [Charts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/creating-a-chart-using-swift-charts)

Also read about using [@State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) in SwiftUI.

```
struct Pellet: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: String
    var count: Int
    var date: Date
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pellets: [Pellet] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(pellets) { pellet in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Date", pellet.date),
                    y: .value("Pellet Count", pellet.count),
                    series: .value("Axolotl", "A")
                )
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
            RuleMark(y: .value("Fixed", 10))
        }
        .chartForegroundStyleScale(["Axolotl" : Color.green])
        .onAppear {
            getData()
        }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        // random data for testing
        var day = 0
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let count = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            let temp = String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5))
            let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(60*60*24*day))
            pellets.append(Pellet(name: temp, type: temp, count: count, date: date))
            day += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Re your last comment,`The data is parsed from strings, which is stored in the Swift 'defaults'.` Don't store this kind of data in the `UserDefaults`,
it is only meant to be used for small bits of setting data.

EDIT-1

If you really want to have a separate variable for your `charliechart`, then use this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pellets: [Pellet] = []
    
    @ViewBuilder private var charliechart: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(pellets) { pellet in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("Date", pellet.date),
                    y: .value("Pellet Count", pellet.count),
                    series: .value("Axolotl", "A")
                )
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
            RuleMark(y: .value("Fixed", 10))
        }
        .chartForegroundStyleScale(["Axolotl" : Color.green])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        charliechart
            .onAppear {
                getData()
            }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        // random data for testing
        var day = 0
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let count = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            let temp = String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5))
            let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(60*60*24*day))
            pellets.append(Pellet(name: temp, type: temp, count: count, date: date))
            day += 1
        }
    }
}
```